# SSRS parameter value relationship

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I know this is probably and easy fix but I have been killing myself trying to code it correctly.

I have a `customerID` and a `CustomerName` columns that I pulled from a query in the `Customers` dataset. The `customerID` is used in other queries (`GetBalance` etc). When I am designing the report, I want to be able to put the matching `@CustomerName` in a textbox, not the `@customerID` (which I can do simply by drag drop) that I am actually using as a parameter in the other queries.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the 'Lookup' expression but I am unsure how to write it

I tried this but it didnt work

```
=Lookup(Parameters!customerID.Value, 
        Fields!CustID.Value, Fields!CustAlias.Value, "Customers")`
```

Comment: is CustomerName the label for your parameter?  You can do `Parameters!CustomerName.Label` if so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parameter is an object that has the properties `Value` (referenced by @ParameterName) and `Label` (what you display to select that parameter value). In your case the `customerID` parameter gets its values and labels from your query. Accordingly, `@customerID` will be the value of the parameter. However, all the properties of the parameter are referencable via the `Parameters` collection.

Use this as your textbox expression:

```
=Parameters!customerID.Label
```

Comment: damn you guys are so smart! I gotta improve my skills to be like you. Thanks